# Getting LazyInitializationException on JUnit Test Case

Tags: spring, hibernate, junit, jpa-2.0, spring-data

Problem running JUnit Test inside a Spring MVC Application. Test 1 (insertTweet) seems to run fine, however on Test 2 I get an "LazyInitializationException" Exception (see full stactrace below).  I understand why it is thrown but not sure why the session is closing and how to reopen it at the begining of every test 2 (or keep the existing session open for the remaining tests to complete)?  I have pasted the entire StackTrace thrown along with Test Classes.

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.project.user.User.tweets, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:566)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:545)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.write(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:370)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.add(PersistentBag.java:291)
    at com.project.core.tweet.Tweet.<init>(Tweet.java:113)
    at com.project.core.service.impl.FanoutServiceTester.insertTweet(FanoutServiceTester.java:69)
    at com.project.core.service.impl.FanoutServiceTester.testInsertRetweet(FanoutServiceTester.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

---

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({ServiceTestExecutionListener.class})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public abstract class AbstractServiceImplTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em;

    @Autowired protected TweetService tweetService;
    @Autowired protected UserService userService;

}


public class FanoutServiceTester extends AbstractServiceImplTest{
    private static User user = null;
    private static User userTwo = null;



    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        user = userService.findByUserId(1);


        //UserTwo Follows User One
        userTwo  = userService.findByUserId(2);



    }


    @Test
    public final void testInsertTweet() {       
        insertTweet();

        //Assert Here

    }



    @Test
    public final void testInsertRetweet() {
        insertTweet();
        //Assert Here

    }


    private Tweet insertTweet(){
        Tweet tweet = new Tweet(user);
        String text = "This is a Message";  
        tweet.setTweetText(text);
        Tweet saved = tweetService.save(tweet);
        return saved;
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you expect us to do with what you've shown? Post your config and your test.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've run into this and the error is a bit misleading. The `Session` is not being closed.

When you call `userService.findByUserId(1);` it probably does a `Join` to a `Tweets` table and so you get this collection back:

```
com.project.user.User.tweets
```

Hibernate does not initialize this collection by default. To initialize it, you can call `Hibernate.initialize()` for example, like this:

```
Hibernate.initialize(user.getTweets());
```

Of course substitute `getTweets()` for the actual method that returns the `tweets` collection.

Comment: That seems to work. However I'm working with JPA 2 and having "Hibernate.initialize()" inside a JPA Entity Class seems odd.  Could it be that junit is calling hibernate instead of jpa?

Comment: Yes that would be odd :-) Then the `Tweets` collection in the entity needs to be fetched eagerly (it will be lazy, i.e. retrieved but not initialized, by default). Try annotating with `@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Unless I'm missing something, If I explicitly define it to "Eagerly" Load the Collection, I expect it to do just that.  Besides, I'd like to exhaust all other options first.

Comment: What's wrong with eagerly loading the collection in this case?

Comment: Tweets Collection may contain a lot of records.  If I was to "Eagerly" Load this Collection then every time I load the "User" Object, it will also load the Tweets Collection, which can lead to performance issues.

Comment: You are still using Hibernate in the project, right? Since Hibernate falls back on JPA where JPA can do the job, i.e. JPA Entities, I think it would still be ok to initialize the collection with Hibernate.initialize() right before you need to access it in your test case. I don't think JPA has an initialize collection method.

Comment: Aren't you accessing the tweets somewhere in your code? i.e. when you retriever the user, `user.getTweets().get(0)` or something along those lines?

Comment: I added the line in method @Before which seems to work.  I wonder, if this Exception is thrown when running the actual application on server.

Comment: I would expect it whenever a lazily fetched collection is accessed before being initialized, just take care to initialize it before using it and it will not throw the exception on the server

Answer (score 89):

> add the `@Transactional` on your test methods – [ben75](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1818045/ben75) Nov 6 '13 at 14:29

Yeah, I have solved the problem:

```
        @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
        @ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:applicationContext.xml"})
        @Transactional
        public class UserinfoActionTest extends StrutsSpringJUnit4TestCase<UserinfoAction> {
                @Test
            public void testLogin2(){
                          request.setParameter("jsonQueryParam", param);
                String str = null;
        try {

                    str = executeAction("/login.action");
                    HashMap<String,List<TUserinfo>> map = (HashMap<String,List<TUserinfo>>)findValueAfterExecute("outDataMap"); }
 catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }


        @Controller
        @Results({  
            @Result(name="json",type="json"
                    , params={"root","outDataMap","excludeNullProperties","true"
                            ,"excludeProperties","^ret\\[\\d+\\]\\.city\\.province,^ret\\[\\d+\\]\\.enterprise\\.userinfos","enableGZIP","true"
                    })
        })
        public class UserinfoAction extends BaseAction {
                    @Action(value="login")

            public String login(){
                if(jsonQueryParam!=null && jsonQueryParam.length()>0)
                {
                    user = JsonMapper.fromJson(jsonQueryParam, TUserinfo.class);
                }
                Assert.notNull(user);
                 //RESULT="ret" addOutJsonData: put List<TUserinfo> into outDataMap with key RESULT for struts2 JSONResult  
                addOutJsonData(RESULT, service.login(user));
                return JSON;
            }
```

Comment: Interesting discussion of transactional: https://www.marcobehler.com/2014/06/25/should-my-tests-be-transactional

Comment: Having @Transactional in integration test is a nightmare, which can lead to wrongly evaluated tests. Just avoid it and do your test as it should be. https://www.kode-krunch.com/2021/07/hibernate-traps-transactional.html

Answer (score 14):

You are missing the `TransactionalTestExecutionListener`.
It is required and present by default when you don't define any TestExecutionListener yourself. But as soon as you define one explicitely : it is removed.

So declare it :

```
@TestExecutionListeners({ServiceTestExecutionListener.class, TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class})
```

See "[Testing - Transaction management](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-tx)" of the 3.2.x Spring docs.

Comment: I made the changes as suggested but I am still getting the mentioned exception.

Comment: add the `@Transactional` on your test methods

Comment: I added that too. I think all that is not necessary if you're extending AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests Class, which I am doing.

Comment: I got the same issue fixed in JUnit test case by just adding `TransactionalTestExecutionListener` to the listeners. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 12):

Enjoy

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional // The magic is here
public class YourClassTests {

...

}
```

Comment: No, please no. I am finding this in projects, that are done by try-and-let-see-what-it-does developers.